# How to update the progressbar with asynctask after re-entrying the activity again in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to implement some functions like file downloading which the download kickoff buttons lie in some list view. To make it more clear, here to illustrate it with graph.

First, I enter Book1_Activity with some list view there:
[book_chapter_name_1  [download_1]]
[book_chapter_name_2  [download_2]] 
I clicked download_1 button, and the downloading is kicked off and there is a progress bar which shows the degree of the progress. The downloading is achieved by an AsyncTask.

After that, I'd like to switch to some other activity, let's say book_read_activity, so that I could download some books while keep reading still.

My problem is after I read the book, when I'd like to check the progress of the downloaded books, so I reentry the Book1_Activity, since Book1_Activity is destroyed and recreated， how could I get the download progress and update it？

Comment: can you upload your AsyncTask code..???
so can be more understandable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considered using a service instead? Then you could have it running even if closed?
But if you want to go on with your approach I'd have the asynctask write progress to a global access point and then read progress from there.

Comment: Service might be okay with the background work. But there seems no way to update the ui with service for this situation. The global access point is what I'm trying to do now. But it do mess around the code. Any there is a solution there.

Comment: @david.wan Service together with a custom broadcast might be plausible.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I use all the time. I do not talk about your UI, your listbox update etc.. It's just the Task and ProgressDialog handling:

A style for the ProgressDialog:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyProgressDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My ProgressDialog class:

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.MyProgressDialog);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message) {
        return show(context, title, message, false);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
        return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
        return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener onCancelListener) {
        MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(onCancelListener);
        dialog.setTitle(title);

        dialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar(context), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        dialog.show();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Now comes the beef. A ListView with an AsyncTask as an inner class. The AsyncTask holds a reference to the surrounding ListActivity (context) and the ListActivity holds a reference to the AsyncTask. The ProgressDialog will be created in the AsyncTask on usual start. If the ListActivity stops and the AsyncTask is still running the dialog will be dismissed from the ListActivity and recreated after restart.

The important thing is to notice who is doing what:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        /* package */ MyListActivity   context;
        /* package */ MyProgressDialog dialog;

        public MyAsyncTask(MyListActivity context) {
            super();

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final Void... voids) {
            Boolean rc = false;

            // Put your running task here

            return rc;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
            if (dialog != null) {
                try {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                }

                dialog = null;
            }

            if (result) {
                // Whatever you need to update in UI
            }

            context.task = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            dialog = MyProgressDialog.show(context, null, null, true, false);
        }
    }

    /* package */ MyAsyncTask task;

    // Save AsyncTask if running, dismiss ProgressDialog if open
    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (task != null) {
            if (task.dialog != null) {
                task.dialog.dismiss();
                task.dialog = null;
            }
        }

        return task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {

        // Usual start here

        // Was task running?
        task = (MyAsyncTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (task != null) {
            // Task was running, update context, restart ProgressDialog
            task.context = this;
            task.dialog = MyProgressDialog.show(this, null, null, true, false);
        } else {
            // Task was not running. Start from beginning
            task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
            task.execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not suitable for my situation here. The asynctask is running in the background, and you've saved it after the activity destroyed, and then reuse it. For me, the book_view activity might be still the same class, and when reentry this activity, I do need to reuse the asynctask with some condition. Which means, the book chapter downloading asynctask should be only reused to the book_view activity that is being downloaded.

Comment: You wrote in your original post that you want to switch to another activity. This implies that the list activity is paused. My example will work exactly for this purpose. Now you write that both activities are in the same class? Sorry bout wasting your time.

Comment: It's me to say sorry to waste your time. Thanks any way. The list activity might be destroyed with my situation, but when came back to the same activity class instance, I need to retrieve the progress for some specified condition.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same in one of my applications (using API 8). I choosed to display the download progress in the notification bar and I used a service to update it. Worked fine for me.

Since I developped my application for the API 8, I couldn't use the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class but you may want to take a look at it. If your application uses API 9+, it seems more appropriate than re-coding the process youself.